# Hodge bundle for $\partial\bar\partial$-manifolds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $\pi:\mathcal X\to B$ be a holomorphic family of $\partial\bar\partial$-manifolds (compact complex manifolds satisfy $\partial\bar\partial$-lemma, e.g. Kähler manifolds, Fujiki class $\mathcal C$ manifolds).  Then my question is:

> Does $\cup_{t\in B}H^{1,1}(X_t,\mathbb R)$ form a vector bundle over $B$?

If we define the Hodge filtration by $
F^pH^k(X,\mathbb C):=\frac{F^pA^k(X)\cap\text{ker }d}{F^pA^k(X)\cap\text{im }d},$ then for a $\partial\bar\partial$-manifold $X$ we have $F^pH^k(X,\mathbb C)=\bigoplus_{r\ge p}H^{r,k-r}(X),$ since the Hodge to de Rham spectral sequence of $X$ degenerates at $E_1$.

According to [an answer of Arapura](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/381058/is-the-hodge-bundle-a-holomorphic-vector-bundle), we need to give a definition of $\cup_{t\in B}H^{p,q}(X_t,\mathbb R)$. First, we define $\mathcal H^k:=R^k\pi_*\mathbb C\otimes \mathcal C^{\infty}_{\mathbb C}$ (does here need a underline on $\mathcal C^{\infty}_{\mathbb C}$?). Actually, I'm not sure I understand what is $R^k\pi_*\mathbb C\otimes \mathcal C^{\infty}_{\mathbb C}$ correctly (I have checked Voisin's book *Hodge theory and complex algebraic geometry, I*, p.99, but the formal definitions of right derived functor and left-exact functor just make me more confused)， my understanding is that: for the resolution of $\mathbb C$
$$0\to \mathbb C\to A^0\to A^1\to\cdots,$$ the derived functor is defined by
$$R^i\pi_*\mathbb C:= H^i (\pi_*(A^\bullet)) = \frac {\mathrm{ker}\big(\pi_*(A^i) \to \pi_*(A^{i+1})\big) }{ \mathrm{im} \big( \pi_*(A^{i-1}) \to \pi_*(A^i) \big)},$$
after extension of differentiable functions, we get $R^k\pi_*\mathbb C\otimes \mathcal C^{\infty}_{\mathbb C}$, but why does it form a vector bundle? I know for $t\in B$, all $H^k(X_t,\mathbb C)$ are isomorphic to $H^k(X,\mathbb C)$, but in order to make it a vector bundle, there should be local trivialisations for open covers $U_i$ of $B$ or transition functions between different open sets, is it self obvious if defined by $R^k\pi_*\mathbb C\otimes \mathcal C^{\infty}_{\mathbb C}$?

Then, the filtration induces a subbundle $F^p\mathcal H^k:=\cup_{t\in B}F^pH^k(X_t)$ of $\mathcal H^k$, does the invariance of the dimensions of $F^pH^k(X_t,\mathbb C)$ suffice to prove the bundles $F^p\mathcal H^k$ are vector bundles?

Define the subbundle $\mathcal H^k_{\mathbb R}$ of $\mathcal H^k$ by $\mathcal H^k_{\mathbb R}:=\cup_{t\in B}H^k(X_t,\mathbb R)$, then the bundle $\cup_{t\in B}H^{1,1}(X_t,\mathbb R)$ can be defined by $F^1\mathcal H^2\cap \mathcal H^2_{\mathbb R}$, does it suffice to prove $\cup_{t\in B}H^{1,1}(X_t,\mathbb R)$ is a vector bundle over $B$?

Comment: The first part about vector bundles is a form of [Serre–Swan theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serre%E2%80%93Swan_theorem).

Comment: @Z.M, I don't see $\mathcal H^k$ being a vector bundle has any relation with the Serre-Swan theorem which states a section is finitely generated and projective.

Comment: $\mathcal H^k$ is a finite projective module over the sheaf of smooth functions.

Comment: @Z.M, do you mean for the resolution of $\mathbb C$
$$0\to \mathbb C\to A^0\to A^1\to\cdots,$$ the derived functor is defined by
$$R^i\pi_*\mathbb C:= H^i (\pi_*(A^\bullet)) = \frac {\mathrm{ker}\big(\pi_*(A^i) \to \pi_*(A^{i+1})\big) }{ \mathrm{im} \big( \pi_*(A^{i-1}) \to \pi_*(A^i) \big)},$$
after extension of differentiable functions, we get $R^k\pi_*\mathbb C\otimes \mathcal C^{\infty}_{\mathbb C}$, and it is obviously a finite projective module, so it forms a vector bundle?

Comment: It is not obviously a finite projective module, but under you assumptions, the cohomological groups of the derived pushforward are probably local systems, and after tensoring with the sheaf of smooth functions, they become vector bundles with integrable connection. They should be related to Gauß–Manin connection.